# GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT and gameWidth, gameHeight

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am learning how to make games with Vanilla JS. The instructor is using `GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT` at the `index.js`; and `gameWidth, gameHeight` at the `paddle.js`. When he uses the latter, I see that there is an explanation pop-up near the latter one saying that it is considered `GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT` when he hovers over `gameWidth, gameHeight`.

But when I try to hover over `gameWidth, gameHeight`; it says `any`. Could anyone explain the difference?

By the way the instructor uses `Sandbox`, I am using `VS Code` if that has anything to do with it.

`index.js`

```
import Paddle from './paddle.js';

let canvas = document.getElementById('gameScreen');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const GAME_WIDTH = 800;
const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

let paddle = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
```

`paddle.js`

```
export default class Paddle {
  constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
    this.gameWidth = gameWidth;
    this.width = 150;
    this.height = 20;

    this.maxSpeed = 7;
    this.speed = 0;

    this.position = {
      x: gameWidth - 100 - this.width - 100,
      y: gameHeight - this.height - 10,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the capitalized constants (GAME_WIDTH) are the actual data containers that exist in the global scope.
the camel-case variables are function arguments and only live within the function's lifetime.

the script first sets the constants as default.
Then later it uses them to initiate the Paddle's constructor. But he could send any number to that constructor really.
As such there's no relation between the constants and the variables outside this one usage (afaics)

edit: the relation between them in your instructors editor is most likely a feature of said editor.